# Accessing text fields in a stored procedure and insert to another table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to access a “text” type and inserting that value into another table viw a stored procedure. I’ve tried to cast it, convert it, but nothing works.

My code looks somethings like this:

```
Declare @Critique varchar(max), @Feedback varchar(max)
…
…
…
SELECT @Critique = CAST(comments as varchar(max)), @Feedback = CAST(public_critique as varchar(max)) FROM ASCO_vEXTERNAL_REVIEW_APPLICATIONS_LIST WHERE wf_task_assignment_id = @WfTaskAssignmentIDP1

– comments and public_critique are defined as text in view (also tried with table) ASCO_vEXTERNAL_REVIEW_APPLICATIONS_LIST
…
…
…
insert into WF_TASK_ASSIGNMENT_REVIEW (wf_task_assignment_review_id, wf_task_assignment_id, grantee_project_id, comments, public_critique) values (@NewID1, @WfTaskAssignmentIDP2, @GranteeProjectID, @Critique, @Feedback)
```

Can you please help me with this as soon as possible. I would really appreciate this.

Thanks,
Harish

Comment: what are the columns type of the WF_TASK_ASSIGNMENT_REVIEW table ?

Comment: what happens when you run the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not sound good to understand .

Dont use **text** ,it wont support in many cases like where ,group by etc , so try  use varchar

This is just an example

```
Declare @Critique varchar(max)
set @Critique = (select public_critique  from ASCO_vEXTERNAL_REVIEW_APPLICATIONS_LIST 
 where convert(varchar(50), wf_task_assignment_id ) =@WfTaskAssignmentIDP1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the `WF_TASK_ASSIGNMENT_REVIEW` is the one containing the `text` column you're trying to write into.

The `text` type is now deprecated in SQL 2005 and 2008. If at all possible try and upgrade the `WF_TASK_ASSIGNMENT_REVIEW` table to use the `nvarchar(max)` type instead.

If not, the only way is to use the `WRITETEXT` statement to write into the target column, in a loop (since `WRITETEXT` has an upper limit). See the `WRITETEXT statement` example in the SQL Server docs.